# Dynamics CRM 2011: Increase SQL connection pool size

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

At this blogpost i see that there is a limit of 100 concurrent connections to SQL server from Dynamics CRM 2011.

https://joshimandarblog.wordpress.com/tag/maximum-concurrent-connections/

Is there a way to increase the limit?

I'm running a custom bulk-deletion tool and this limit seems to be a bottle-neck slowing down the process.

Comment: 100 Concurrent connections at one time... i don't think so that it seems to be your problem.
btw which entity data are you trying to delete ??

Comment: Emails, CampaignResponses, Campaigns, Contacts and some custom entities. Contacts actually can't be deleted in parallel at all. Doing that results in many deadlocks and timeouts.